# My VM instance keep disconnecting with internal IP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have a VM instance setup as a database (MongoDB) on GG Cloud and it was working fine until recently it just can't be connected with internal IP. Sometime it was able to connect, but for a few moment and then it get disconnected again.

I have tried use SSH to connect and it works fine. Have anyone encountered with the same issue? or happen to know what might cause this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Did you recently added anything or did your DB perform any change? It seems that internally the network config. has been changed/modified. I'd suggest going to the eth0 files (or whatever the name, according to your O.S. distr.) and checking if everything is on its right place.

Since you are able to SSH into it, it doesn't sound to me like a problem with the instance itself.

Frank